# UiPickerView on UiScrollView?

Tags: iphone

In my app I have a UIPickerView on UIScrollView. When I check the delayContentTouches in IB the UIScrollView scrolls, but UIPickerView do not scrolls smoothly. And If I uncheck it then my UIPickerView scrolls smoothly but UIScrollView do not. UIScrollView is added as subView to my view. All controls are on the UIScrollView. I am unable to figure it out why its behaving like this. Please guide me. Is I am missing something or doing wrong?

Thanks,
Panache.

Comment: The answer to this question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709124/iphone-uiscrollview-is-scrolling-before-uidatepicker-that-is-placed-inside-it