# Scroll view should not scroll when user interacts with slider in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a scroll view which has paging enabled.Its horizontal scrolling so when user scrolled from first page it would land the user in second page and second page has one slider.when the user slides(not touches) on this slider it automatically scrolls to first page because its horizontal scrolling too.Unless its touch on slider user end up in going to first page though user not intended to go to first page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem once but with another control.
Take a look ate this answer to see if it canhelp you :

[iPhone - UIScrollView and UIDatePicker scrolling conflict : the one interfer with the second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709124/iphone-uiscrollview-and-uidatepicker-scrolling-conflict-the-one-interfer-wit)

Comment: Controller is already derived from UIViewController if i make it to derive from UIScrollView then it causes abort signal and stops executing...Any suggestions?

Comment: @Vani : They are two different controllers. The qscroll view must not (of course) inherit from UIViewController. This one is probably defined as your XIB Fil's owner. You must subclass a UIScrollView and type you scrollView with that class.

Answer (score 0):

Does the second view on the scrollView contains any other container like WebView or imageView etc.

If you are showing your data directly on the ScrollView (i.e on second page).I recommend that to add a one more view on your scrollView on second view and render your data on that view the you wil be able to use the  main ScrollView and the second view scroll separately.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding actions for `UIControlEventTouchDown`, `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` to your slider. On touch down, do `myScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;` and restore scrolling on touch up.